# Docker postgres container not running before application container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

When I run `docker compose up`, I'm expecting for my postgres_container to run before my go_container since the go_container is dependent on postgres_container as specified in the yml file `depends_on`. However, my go_container is executed first and the postgres_container doesn't seem to ever start.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  go_container:
    container_name: go_container
    environment:
      - DATABASE_USER=${DATABASE_USER}
      - DATABASE_PASSWORD=${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
      - DATABASE_NAME=${DATABASE_NAME}
      - DATABASE_HOST=${DATABASE_HOST}
      - DATABASE_PORT=${DATABASE_PORT}
      - API_KEY=${API_KEY}
    build: .
    ports:
     - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - .:/src
    depends_on:
      - postgres_container
    restart: on-failure
    networks:
      - weather
  postgres_container:
    container_name: postgres_container 
    user: postgres
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DATABASE_USER}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${DATABASE_NAME}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./sql/create.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create.sql
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready", "-U", "${DATABASE_USER}"]
    networks:
      - weather
volumes:
  db_data: {}
networks:
  weather:
    driver: bridge
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM golang:1.21.5

EXPOSE 8080

WORKDIR /src

COPY .env .

COPY . .

RUN go mod download && go mod verify

WORKDIR /src/cmd/app

RUN go run main.go
```

At first, my docker-compose.yml was respecting the `depends_on` key but after some changes it stopped. Im not sure at what point it stopped working. I thought it was a bug in my docker installation so I tired reinstalling Docker but the problem persists.

.env file

```
DATABASE_HOST=postgres_container
DATABASE_PORT=5432
DATABASE_USER=postgres
DATABASE_PASSWORD=postgres
DATABASE_NAME=weather
SERVER_PORT=8080
```

Here are the logs:
[docker log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHork.png)

Comment: Where is `DATABASE_USER` defined? Can you verify that the health check on the `postgres_container` is executed correctly and successfully? You may want to specify that the application is started after the database has become ready, see [here (`github.com`)](https://github.com/turing85/spring-join/blob/main/local-deployment/docker-compose.yml#L31-L33) for an example.

Comment: The DATABASE_USER is defined in a .env file. When I run the postgres_container independently `docker compose up -d postgres_container` the health check passes

Comment: Can you share a [MRE], e.g. in form of a github repository?

Comment: I added the .env to the original question

Comment: The build command fails. `RUN` is executed at container buildtime, not image runtime. Please replace the `RUN` in the last line of the containerfile with a `CMD` or `ENTRYPOINT`. For the exact syntax, please look at the corresponding documentation of [`CMD` (`docs.docker.com`)](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) and [`ENTRYPOINT` (`docs.docker.com`)](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we take a look at the logs, we see that the image build process fails. Looking closely at the containerfile, we see the following on the last line:

```
...
RUN go run main.go
```

`RUN` is executed at image buildtime, not container runtime. In contrast, `depends_on` in the `docker-compose.yml` controls the order in which containers are started; it has no effect for image building.

To fix this issue, we need to either use [`CMD` (`docs.docker.com`)](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd), [`ENTRYPOINT` (`docs.docker.com`)](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) or a combination of both to define the command. I will continue using the `ENTRYPONT` approach:

```
...
ENTRYPOINT [ "go", "run", "main.go" ]
```

Please also look at [@larsks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/147356/larsks)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77672708/4216641). Their answer has a valid point with regards to startup order.

---

A remark: it is strange to use `go run ...` in a containerile to run the code. I would recommend compiling the code first, and then executing the result of the compilation. We can achieve this with a [multi-stage build (`docs.docker.com`)](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-stage/). I also wrote a [blog article discussing multi-stage containerfiles (`turing85.github.io`)](https://turing85.github.io/articles/2023/04-02-multistage-containerfiles/index.html). An example can be found [here (`github.com`)](https://github.com/turing85/go-gin-qr/blob/main/build/package/containerfiles/Containerfile.build-in-container).

Answer (score 1):

The `depends_on` directive, as you've used it here, is almost entirely useless, because the dependency is only on container startup. That is, `go_container` starts after `postgres_container` has started, but that doesn't mean that Postgres is actually ready to service connections.

You can use the extended form of the `depends_on` directive to achieve the ordering you want. See [this documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/); the resulting configuration would look something like:

```
services:
  go_container:
    container_name: go_container
    environment:
      - DATABASE_USER=${DATABASE_USER}
      - DATABASE_PASSWORD=${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
      - DATABASE_NAME=${DATABASE_NAME}
      - DATABASE_HOST=${DATABASE_HOST}
      - DATABASE_PORT=${DATABASE_PORT}
      - API_KEY=${API_KEY}
    build: .
    ports:
     - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - .:/src
    depends_on:
      postgres_container:
        condition: service_healthy
    restart: on-failure
    networks:
      - weather

  postgres_container:
    container_name: postgres_container 
    user: postgres
    image: postgres:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DATABASE_USER}
      - POSTGRES_DB=${DATABASE_NAME}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./sql/create.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create.sql
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready", "-U", "${DATABASE_USER}"]
    networks:
      - weather
volumes:
  db_data: {}
networks:
  weather:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: Alright, I made the following changes but the problem persists. Its as if my postgres_container never starts up when I execute `docker compose up`

Comment: Added an image of my logs to the OP so that you can see that the postgres container never starts up

Comment: can you post the logs from the container that gets spun for docker service ? `docker logs container name.`

Comment: There aren't any logs for the container. The only logs available is the screenshot I posted

Comment: The postgres_container runs fine when I run it independenlty but when I try to run it with the other golang service it never starts up.